# SoapUI - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, soapui

I am getting the following error message when trying to generate Axis1.x Artifacts.
I checked and decreased the max heap size:

"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\SoapUI-5.0.0.vmoptions"

-Xms128m

-Xmx256m

[image]

Could anyone please advise how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: -v, --verbose; print informational messages
source: http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html#WSDL2Java_Reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I was trying to generate the class stubs from WSDL2Java (Axis 1.x).
I had to download the Axis 1.3 version and point Tools (Axis 1.3) to the Axis 1.3 installation.

[image]

I am able to generate code now.